# PQgetvalue() strips spaces from result of string_agg()

Tags: postgresql, c-api

I have a GNU C++ project that uses the PostgreSQL API and for some reason, it strips spaces from the result of a certain query. Other environments (`psql` and pgAdmin) don't. The query is:

```
SELECT string_agg(my_varchar, ', ') FROM my table;
```

Notice the space after the comma in the delimiter. Instead of `1046976, 1046977` being returned by `PQgetvalue()`, I get `1046976,1046977`. Just for kicks, I tried changing the delimiter to silly things like `string_agg(my_varchar, ',:) '` and `string_agg(my_varchar, ', :)'`. It *doesn't* strip the space if the space is in the *middle* of the delimiter.

Again, I don't have this problem if I do the same queries in db browsers like `psql` and pgAdmin; they don't strip the space in any of those queries.

Yes, I considered the possibility that because the columns from which they extract are `varchar`s, but the data are 7-bit integers, the engine might be confused. I changed the query to something that is truly a `varchar`, but the spaces were still stripped.

Looking at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html, I see that `string_agg()` expects its arguments to be `text`s or `bytea`s. Well, I never got an error, but to be sure, I tried `string_agg(my_varchar::text, ', '::text)`. It didn't make a difference.

I don't know a great deal about this API, but it doesn't appear to connect to the db with any options, so I don't think there's much to say about the configuration.

I'm running this in GNU C++ v4.9.2 on Debian 8.10. The PostgreSQL engine and API are 9.4.

Comment: I don't believe that. Can you provide a simple program that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Looks like you were right not to. I found this naughty little bit of code `field.remove( QRegExp("\\s+$") );` deep in our framework (far older than my employment here) which would remove spaces when it felt like it.